# angularjs jsonp request fails

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jsonp, angularjs-http

I'm trying to do a jsonp request to a server.
However, I don't seem to get it to work at all...

What I've been trying is to request it using this code:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http({
        url: 'http://teacher.standoutcms.se/questions.js/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK',
        method: 'jsonp',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/javascript' }
    }).success(function(response) {
        deferred.resolve(response);
    }).error(function(response) {
        deferred.reject(response);
    });
  return deferred.promise;
```

The response I get is an error and it says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: JSON_CALLBACK is not defined questions.js?callback=?:1
```

I've tried using a regular Jquery and still the same thing happens.

Last but not least I've managed to get it to work with this code:

```
var url = "http://teacher.standoutcms.se/questions.js?callback=?";
$http.jsonp(url);

$window.JSON_CALLBACK = function(response){
  return response;
}
```

Only thing here is I cant use success, error or var deferred = $q.defer(); to wait on response...

I've been trying all day, please help me :/

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've it working here http://plnkr.co/edit/Sj4j8kXXAlPCEst0xg3W?p=preview which doesn't throw error but the problem is that the interface you are calling returns wrong MIME, it's `text/html` but should be `application/json` i think any workaround would be hacke it's best to contact the developers if you can

Comment: Oh I gave the wrong url! Could you try with the updated in the question again?

I get Uncaught ReferenceError: JSON_CALLBACK is not defined questions.js?callback=?:1, nothing about mimetype :/

Comment: I don't see a difference in URL from your question and then one I have in plnkr

Comment: Sorry mate, you're right. Ill just drop this til tomorrow and Ill talk to the developers :) Thanks for the help, appreciate it a lot!